# fluent nhibarnate doesn't delete orpahns

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

I found some similar threads but all got my code as answer.

I am using One-to-Many relationship.

father mapping:

```
  HasMany(x => x.Targetings).KeyColumn("fk_campaign_id").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Inverse().AsBag();
```

and the child is :

```
 References(x => x.NhCampaign).Column("fk_campaign_id");
```

where the father has a list of child. 
All is working - inserting and updating.
but for some reason when I empty the list in the Father or just want to delete list item, it doesn't delete the child from the database. even if the list is empty.

this is how i update:

```
 using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    session.Update(FatherObject);
                    //session.SaveOrUpdate(oCampaign);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
```

Am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it using the `Not.LazyLoad()` method.